# "dpkg was interrupted error" when installing any application

Tags: software-installation

I have ubuntu 11.10 and when I run any package management command in terminal I get this message

```
E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a'
to correct the problem.
```

What is the problem and how can I solve it?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!) It's never safe to publish your email address on an open web site. I've removed it from the post. If you're sure you want it to be publicly visible, you can undo this revision. Note that askubuntu.com can automatically inform you of answers to your question. More information on this can be found [here](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1781/how-to-handle-contect-postings-containing-addresses)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error message usually points to having interrupted a download in the past.

This should be resolved by the following:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Comment: yes but i don't remember what i was installing then  i cancel it

Comment: doesnt really matter - just copy and paste the commands above and it should resolve your package installation issues.

Comment: yes  . thank u  , problem solved  by u  ,,,,, thank u again

Comment: ````sudo dpkg --configure -a```` is enough now